# vba object reference from userform not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am working and have hit a bit of a roadblock. For one I am not the strongest programmer, I was just given this task but have hit a roadblock (I think its syntax but not sure).

We have done a lot of research to find some data correlations for some of our less technical consultants, and this VBA tool is going to be a quick reference for them to give customers real time projections. The subject is irrelevant to the question.

I have created a class to contain the values, and then the plan was to reference the class from the VBA userform. When I reference the class, I don't get the value that I have stored, but I get the name of the property.

```
Private Sub ddMonthOfUse_Change()

Dim mv As String

Set chillWater = New clsMonth
    With chillWater
        .Janurary = 0.7136
        .Feburary = 0.6755
        .March = 0.6528
        .April = 0.7773
        .May = 0.8213
        .June = 0.8715
        .July = 0.9
        .August = 1.0243
        .September = 1.0516
        .October = 0.8514
        .November = 0.7095
        .December = 0.6994
    End With

Set DX = New clsMonth
    With DX
        .Janurary = 0.5777
        .Feburary = 0.5536
        .March = 0.5166
        .April = 0.6112
        .May = 0.7035
        .June = 0.75
        .July = 0.8
        .August = 0.8345
        .September = 0.9333
        .October = 0.6865
        .November = 0.5976
        .December = 0.4907
    End With


    MsgBox chillWater.month

    End Sub
```

In the class module I have this

```
 Option Explicit

'property decleration
Public Janurary As Single
Public Feburary As Single
Public March As Single
Public April As Single
Public May As Single
Public June As Single
Public July As Single
Public August As Single
Public September As Single
Public October As Single
Public November As Single
Public December As Single
Public chillWater As clsMonth, DX As clsMonth

Public Property Get month() As String

month = Main.ddMonthOfUse.value

End Property
```

Instead of the message box returning the value, if the user selects month March the message box says "March." If, for example, I replace the reference to the dropdown and just type March, I get the value.

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Please keep in mind I am not a veteran programmer at all, I have very rudimentary knowledge of the subject so I could be completely off here. Also I should mention that the message box is not the final use of the information, I was just testing to see if I was calling it correctly.

Comment: What is `Main.ddMonthOfUse`?

Comment: That is the combobox in the userform

Comment: I assume you have fill your combobox with "January February March ...", it is it ?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I can't figure out what `month` is *supposed* to be doing - all I can say is that coupling the default instance of your UserForm to all instances of that `clsMonth` class is a very very very bad idea.

Comment: Correct, it fills it on the userform initializing.

Comment: @Mat'sMug when the combobox in the userform is selected (say the user chooses May), I want the message box to display the value of chillwater.May

Comment: I was told creating a class would be the easiest way to do this, but I have never done that before so this is all very new to me. I think using the get method is giving me problems, I have never used it till today

Comment: Just to notice the spelling of "Janurary" and "Feburary"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *@Mat'sMug when the combobox in the userform is selected (say the user chooses May), I want the message box to display the value of chillwater.May*

Okay, got it. Remove all these, they're toxic:

```
Public chillWater As clsMonth, DX As clsMonth

Public Property Get month() As String

month = Main.ddMonthOfUse.value

End Property
```

You need to expose a `Function` that takes a month's name and returns the corresponding field's value.

One way could be to leverage `CallByName` and do something like this:

```
Public Function ValueFor(ByVal monthName As String) As Single
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim instance As Object
    Set instance = Me 'CallByName can't take "Me" directly

    Dim result As Single
    result = CallByName(instance, monthName, VbGet)

CleanExit:
    ValueFor = result
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    result = 0
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

Notice the `VbGet` parameter - it's going to work with a public field (I just tested it), but ideally you would *encapsulate* these values and expose them as *properties* instead. I like encapsulating my stuff like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TMonth '"T" + ClassName, just by convention
    January As Single
    February As Single
    '...
    December As Single
End Type

Private this As TMonth 'the only private field you need!

'now expose a property accessor for each member:

Public Property Get January() As Single
    January = this.January
End Property

Public Property Let January(ByVal value As Single)
    this.January = value
End Property

'...
```

---

And then your form code can do this:

```
Set chillWater = New clsMonth
With chillWater
    .Janurary = 0.7136
    .Feburary = 0.6755
    .March = 0.6528
    .April = 0.7773
    .May = 0.8213
    .June = 0.8715
    .July = 0.9
    .August = 1.0243
    .September = 1.0516
    .October = 0.8514
    .November = 0.7095
    .December = 0.6994

    MsgBox "Value for " & ddMonthOfUse.value & ": " & .ValueFor(ddMonthOfUse.Value)

End With
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for your help. I do have a few questions is you get the chance to answer them.

Comment: I am a little confused on the VbGet parameter. Is that a built in VBA function or is that referring to something in your code that I don't see. Second, I'm confused with the first part of the code overall. The part with Dim Instance as Object, and then using that combined with the VbGet. Thanks again

Comment: See [CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760.aspx) docs; the function requires an instance of an object that exposes the member you want to call; in this case the object is `Me` - the current instance; but `Me` cannot be passed directly to `CallByName` for some reason, so you make a copy (`instance`) and pass that instead. The function also requires the name of the member to call and an enum value that tells VBA how it should call it - `VbGet` works for `Property Get` members (and public fields) and says "I'm expecting something to be returned from this call".

Comment: And two more questions now, bare with me. All of this is done in the clsMonth Module, correct? And does the Private Type TMonth eliminate the need for my initial deceleration of all the months in my original code?

Comment: Nah, the `Private Type TMonth` is just making it easier to encapsulate things with properties (vs exposing public fields), and eventually to serialize the data into a binary file, if that's ever needed. I just systematically do it that way, because I don't like exposing public fields in objects. And yes, `TMonth`, the `this` field, the 12 properties and the `ValueFor` function all belong in that class module.

Comment: Would you have any idea why VBA says that ValueFor function is not defined? I am calling it from the form code like you suggested. Again, sorry for so much follow up, you have been so very helpful!

Comment: `ValueFor` should be a function defined in the class module, so you need to access it from an instance of that class, like I do in this answer (the dot in front of it makes it work against the `With` block variable)

Comment: Do you take cash, check, or card? Haha Thanks so much for your help, your generosity is making the world go round!!